# 404 not found (from cache) for Hybrid Fiori app for Android

Tags: android, cordova, http-status-code-404, hybrid-mobile-app, sap-fiori

I have a fiori app that has an embedded IFRAME that makes XMLHttpRequest. The IFRAME src is pointing to "*https://myserver:port/some/path/iframe.html*" and the request within the page is made to the same server - "*https://myserver:port/some/path/request_uri*" (POST request).
This works fine in desktop/mobile browser and Fiori app for iOS but it fails for Android app with "404 Not Found (from cache)". I'm not sure why it load the page fine (*https://myserver:port/some/path/iframe.html*) but fails the request.

Some research seems to indicate that this is caused by Cordova and that I need to add the cordova plugin whitelist - GitHub - apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist: Mirror of Apache Cordova plugin whitelist.

It looks like the request should work fine with the following in the config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```

But it's not working. I've even tried adding very loosely configured CSP meta tag in the iframe page as well as the LaunchPad page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

But the request still seems to be blocked and returns "404 Not Found (from cache)".

Does any one have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: posting code will help better

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try adding allow-navigation to the config.xml.
    `<allow-navigation href="myserver:port/*/*" />`
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

You might also try using the the logcat tool for Android. It might be possible to pinpoint the problem using it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I currently have it at default with <allow-navigation href="*" />. That should be sufficient and would cover above pattern, right? I will check out the logcat tool. Thanks!